# Error message : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT from my own rest server Localhost

Tags: json, kotlin, okhttp, rest

I'm trying to get JSON on android from my own rest server on localhost using okHttp like this:

JSON

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Jadwal Catin 2021",
            "description": "bismillah"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Jadwal Vaksin Covid Lansia",
            "description": "Tanggal 16-Juli-2021 di puskesmas perwira sudah bisa vaksin covi-19 untuk lansia"
        }
    ]
}
```

Data Class

```kotlin
class Placeholder {
    var userId: Int? = null
    var id: Int? = null
    var title: String? = null
    @SerializedName("description")
    var body: String? = null
}
```

Into Recycleview

```
        override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
            val body = response.body!!.string()
            var gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            var result = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Placeholder>::class.java).toList()

            runOnUiThread {
                beritaAdapter.setData(result)
            }
```

Any ideas how should I fix it?

Comment: I think you want `data` from the JSON to be deserialized to your `PlaceHolder` class. `data` is the array you want, but the body you are getting is the object containing `data` and status.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you show here is not just an array of `Placeholder`, it's a JSON object (`{ ... }`), which itself contains 2 properties `status` and `data`. And `data` is an array of objects that partially match your `Placeholder` class.

You can represent the overall JSON by the following class:

```kotlin
class PlaceholdersResponse {
    var status: Boolean
    var data: List<Placeholder>
}
```

And you can access your data array this way:

```kotlin
var result = gson.fromJson(body, PlaceholdersResponse::class.java).data.toList()
```

Comment: Thanks it's work, but how i can get the newest on top my recycleview?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any notion of date inside your JSON. If they are sorted in the JSON from oldest to newest, you can use the `asReversed()` function on the list to get a reversed view on your list.